# Is it ok in android to read from file strings.xml in unit tests to ensure that resource is matches required string?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

I want to achieve 100% code coverage in unit tests, and I realized that nobody writes unit tests that read strings.xml to ensure that a resource with a given ID has the expected value. The same can be done with layouts, such as finding a view with a required ID and checking if it has the maxLines attribute.

It may look strange, but sometimes a developer can change a string that is used in several places. They might want to change only one of them but end up affecting every usage. The same goes for attributes of a view, which you can forget to update after refactoring. Unit tests can protect you from these types of bugs.

Why can't I write UI tests for this? Well, they are much slower, and they require mocking lots of classes, among other things. On the other hand, manually reading from a file to check strings and achieving full code coverage can give you the same guarantees as UI tests

Yes, I know about localization and plurals. They are pretty hard to check using this way (especially plurals). But if my app hasn't any of them is it normal? And if not then why?

Comment: Sure, seems fine to me.

Comment: But why it isn'n widely used? None of tutorials tell about this approach There is no libraries in github which helps to do it

Comment: Why would you need a library to assert that a string is equal to another string?  I don't think there are tutorials since it's kind of a niche use case.

Comment: I need library to read from strings.xml, parse that file and create map resource id -> actual string for further assertions.
I can write it myself but it still strange that nobody tried to do it before

Comment: So write it. Be the helper that you're looking for right now :)

Comment: Oh, yeah, I would probably just use Robolectric or something for this and query the actual resources rather than parsing the XML file.